# Undefined type 'Request'.intelephense(1009)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Iam getting this error in Laravel 8 and Name: PHP Intelephense 1.7.1 installed.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
use Request;


class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (!$request->expectsJson()) {
            if (Request::is('admin/*'))
                return route('admin.login');
            else
                return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

and i have tried to add

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

but still the same any ideas?

Thanks for help ...

Comment: Do you use Vscode for coding?

Comment: Yes i forget to mention that i use Vscode 1.62.3

Comment: i tried to add 

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

not working also

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Solution 1:** You can solve this problem by installing `laravel-ide-helper` package. Link is [here](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper)

**Solution 2:** Put below code to your `settings.json`

```
  "intelephense.telemetry.enabled": false,
  "intelephense.completion.triggerParameterHints": true,
  "intelephense.completion.insertUseDeclaration": true,
  "intelephense.trace.server": "messages",
  "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedClassConstants": false,
  "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedFunctions": false,
  "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedConstants": false,
  "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedProperties": false,
  "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedTypes": false,
  "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedMethods": false,
```

And finally don't forget to restart vscode.

Comment: thank you solved. How can I make other settings? so from where did you find these json settings?

Comment: @malibil Use vsc? if yes, then `ctrl+p` on the search bar do `>open user settings` and on the `Extensions` search want you want to customize.. when you change it goes to the `settings.json`

Comment: Solution 2 is the proper one if you are running an older version of Laravel or PHP

Comment: Solution 3 for me ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

"**Laravel Snippets**" - VScode install the plugin.

Maybe it will be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

F1 -> Reload Window -> Enter